# I can't export a GCP autoML model to a bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl, automl

I already exported models to a bucket before using the WebUI, but today when i am trying to export a new model don't show to me the option to chose where to save the model.

[After click on 'Container'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTc6d.png)

I already try use the CMD mode but, a error is raised that the server can not find the file.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsyiG.png)

Answer (score 2):

Based on your screenshot, you did not yet **Deploy your model**. You need to [deploy a model before exporting](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/edge-quickstart#deploy_the_model) it to your preferred format.

> Before you can export your model you must deploy it for use.

EDIT:
You might still encounter this even after deploying, since there is a known issue on the UI of AutoML see this [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/178778387) for updates